# JSON RPC "invalid payload" message"

Tags: php, rpc, xml-rpc, bitcoin, json-rpc

I am trying to make some calls to my bitcoin wallet using the API provided at (https://blockchain.info/api/json_rpc_api)

I am using the PHP wrapper files from the site given above.

I am  trying to call the can_connect method to make sure all my parameters are right, bit it returns as

> Invalid return payload: enable debugging to examine incoming payload Invalid data

Looking at the files, I see there are both xmlrpc and jsonrpc includes. I am curious if the wrong one is being called ?

My code:

```
    <?php
include "AuctionFunctions.inc.php";

$btc = getConnection();
$canConnect = $btc->can_connect();
//echo $canConnect;
printf($canConnect);

//if ($canConnect) {
//  $status = setup();
//  echo $status;
//}
?>
```

this method should return a boolean value. Instead, this is what it returns (I enabled debug mode like the initial error said to do)

Note: I tried the advice at https://github.com/mikegogulski/bitcoin-php/issues/7
However, that did not fix the problem.

> > ---GOT--- HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 11 Sep 2014 05:32:45 GMT Server: Apache Last-Modified: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 21:23:04 GMT
> >     Accept-Ranges: bytes Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip
> >     Content-Length: 92 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html
>
> ‹³QÔÕU(HLOÍÏVÐÕµã²ñsó€") I• ¥©% º ùÅ%™yéÉ¹ÅF•%¹9@ª
>   (Õb€>ˆÍe£‘ª–>L[
>   ---END---
>
> HEADER: date: Thu, 11 Sep 2014 05:32:45 GMT HEADER: server: Apache
>   HEADER: last-modified: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 21:23:04 GMT HEADER:
>   accept-ranges: bytes HEADER: vary: Accept-Encoding HEADER:
>   content-encoding: gzip HEADER: content-length: 92 HEADER: connection:
>   close HEADER: content-type: text/html
>
> ---INFLATED RESPONSE---[91 chars]---
>
> ```
> pageok
> ```
>
> ---END---
>
> Invalid return payload: enable debugging to examine incoming payload
>   Invalid data

the getConnection() method is in the AuctionFunctions.inc.php file which is included in the file which calls it. AuctionFunctions contains the method as shown:

```
function getConnection() {
$scheme = 'http';
$username = 'username here';
$password = 'password here';
$addresss = 'rpc.blockchain.info';
$port = '80';
$certificate_path = '';
$debug_level = 2;   
$btc = new BitcoinClient($scheme, $username, $password, $address = "localhost", $port = 80, $certificate_path, $debug_level);

return $btc; //returns BitcoinClient object
```

}

the BitcoinClient class is stored in a file called bitcoin.inc, and can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/mikegogulski/bitcoin-php

Comment: Not enough info. What does `getConnection()` do? There's no such function in bitcoin-php. I assume it's something in your `AuctionFunctions.inc.php` file that calls `new BitcoinClient(....)` with a set of parameters, but you don't share them here. What's your request look like?

Comment: @romulusnr, I will update the question to show you